# Showing that a subspace equals the null space or the whole space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $\varphi$ be a linear functional on the vector space $V$ and suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ so that null $\varphi \subseteq U$. Show that either $U=$ null $\varphi$ or $U=V$.

To prove this I thought that the rank nullity theorem as well as properties of the kernel and image would come in handy. I have the following:

dim(null) $\leq$ dim($V$) ; dim(null) $\leq$ dim ($U$); dim(Image) $\leq$ dim(F) ; dim $(U)\leq $ dim ($V$)

With various rearranging of the above inequalities, I haven't found a contradiction. Is there another way I should be thinking about this problem? Thank you.

Comment: If $\phi = 0$ then $\ker \phi = V$, otherwise $\dim \ker \phi = \dim V -1$ (assuming finite, otherwise the codimension is one). Hence there are only two possible dimensions for $U$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is the dimension of the image 1?

Comment: If $\phi \neq 0$ then the image is $\mathbb{R}$ (or whatever field you are using).

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: The key fact here is that if $A,B$ are subspaces such that $\dim A = \dim B $ and $A \subset B$ then $A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\varphi$ is the null function, then $U=V=\ker\varphi$. Otherwise, if $\ker\varphi\varsubsetneq U$, take $u\in U\setminus\ker\varphi$. Then $V=\ker\varphi\bigoplus\langle u\rangle\subset U$, and so $V=U$.

Note that the equality $V=\ker\varphi\bigoplus\langle u\rangle$ comes from the fact that, if $v\in V$, then $v$ is the sum of $v-\frac{\varphi(v)}{\varphi(u)}u\in\ker\varphi$ with $\frac{\varphi(v)}{\varphi(u)}u\in\langle u\rangle$.